# Joining 2 Queries using Left Join

Tags: mysql, sql

These are my queries, I am intending to Join them together and create one, but not sure how.

```
select SN, COUNT(distinct SB)
from SBS
where SB is not null
group by SN  
order by COUNT(Distinct SB) desc


select a.SN, COUNT(distinct a.SB)
from SBS a 
inner join SC b
on a.CN = b.CN
group by a.SN
order by COUNT(distinct a.SB) desc
```

Comment: are you sure you want left join and not union?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to create a query with two columns, one for each count.

For this you can use a `left join` and then aggregation:

```
select a.SN,
       COUNT(distinct case when a.sb is not null then a.SB end) as firstQueryCount,
       COUNT(distinct case when b.CNT is not null then a.SB end) as secondQueryCount
from SBS a left join
     SC b
     on a.CN = b.CN
group by a.SN
order by firstQueryCount desc;
```

Comment: when b.CNT is not null then a.SB end - is the b.CNT means b.count of something.

Comment: For the last line order by firstquerycount desc; I am receiving error Ambiguous column name 'firstquerycount'. How can I fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @Frank . . . Those two columns should not have been in the `select`.

Comment: Thanks!. Yes I figured that out, they were giving 2 more additional columns.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use union sth like

```
select SN, COUNT(distinct SB)
from SBS
where SB is not null
group by SN  
order by COUNT(Distinct SB) desc

union

select a.SN, COUNT(distinct a.SB)
from SBS a 
inner join SC b
on a.CN = b.CN
group by a.SN
order by COUNT(distinct a.SB) desc
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work, I get error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.

Comment: The ORDER BY clause has to come after the UNION, i.e. delete the `order by` line from the first query. Also, UNIONing queries and JOINing them are not the same thing; in one case you get more rows, in the other you get more columns. Which do you want?